# How to modify the value of only one of the keyvalues in the json array of js and keep the others？

Tags: javascript

This is the data that needs to be processed

```
let test=[
  {
    "id": 28620,
    "name": "fenbi1",
    "dn": "chl"
  },
  {
    "id": 5941,
    "name": "fenbi2",
    "dn": "chl"
  },
  {
    "id": 5226,
    "name": "fenbi3",
    "dn": "chl"
  }]
```

The requirement is to change only dn to ch
the changed value is

```
  let test=[
  {
    "id": 28620,
    "name": "fenbi1",
    "dn": "ch"
  },
  {
    "id": 5941,
    "name": "fenbi2",
    "dn": "ch"
  },
  {
    "id": 5226,
    "name": "fenbi3",
    "dn": "ch"
  }]
```

This is the method I used

```
  test=test.map((item)=>({
    'id':item.id,
    'name':item.name,
    'dn':'ch'
  }))
```

This approach works but is not elegant because just to change one value you have to
write the others as well, is there a better way to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a simple for loop might be better than map in this situation

```js
let test=[
  {
    "id": 28620,
    "name": "fenbi1",
    "dn": "chl"
  },
  {
    "id": 5941,
    "name": "fenbi2",
    "dn": "chl"
  },
  {
    "id": 5226,
    "name": "fenbi3",
    "dn": "chl"
  }]

  for (let item of test) {
     item.dn = 'ch'
  }

  console.log(test)
```

Comment: Note that this changes the original object (which is different from what OP's code does, but is consistent with what the text of the question asks).

Comment: How to change the structure without affecting the original values？

Comment: You could copy the object then change the desired field, though this will also "write the other values". If you only want to touch the `dn` property you have to mutate state. Is it important to you to keep the original object? In your original code you are immediately overwriting the old object with the new mapped object.

Answer (score 1):

Use rest syntax to collect the properties other than `dn`, then spread them into the new object.

```js
const test=[{id:28620,name:"fenbi1",dn:"chl"},{id:5941,name:"fenbi2",dn:"chl"},{id:5226,name:"fenbi3",dn:"chl"}];

const output = test.map(({ dn, ...rest }) => ({ dn: 'ch', ...rest }));
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Note that this does not change the original object (which is functionally equivalent to OP's code, but is not what the text of the question asks).

Answer (score 0):

You can write code like this.

```
let test=[
   {
      "id": 28620,
      "name": "fenbi1",
      "dn": "chl"
   },
   {
      "id": 5941,
      "name": "fenbi2",
      "dn": "chl"
   },
   {
      "id": 5226,
      "name": "fenbi3",
      "dn": "chl"
   }]
```

Now use array.map()

```
const newArray = test.map(e => ({...e,dn:"ch"}));
```

Comment: Deconstructive assignment is also good